# React Big Calendar. Day Timeline layout

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Is it possible create Timeline layout with custom views?
Maybe someone implemented something like this?[image]

Comment: Hi, You can refer fullcalendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-resource-render-hook-demo

Comment: @HpLam, Timeline layout in Fullcalendar it's plugin. And to use this plugin you need a license key, but it is paid, and expensive.That's why I asked exactly about React-big-calendar